# Rotate Item on hover and retain that position on mouse leave

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do some animation with css that is rotate an Item 360deg and retain this rotation when mouse leaves, that is the animation should not run when mouse leaves the element.
Here is what I have now

```css
.customer-item {
  width: 150px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 3px solid rgb(240, 240, 240);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .8s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 2s ease-in-out;
}

.customer-item:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
  transform: rotateY(360deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="row col-md-10 mx-auto justify-content-center">
  <div class="customer-item" <img src="./images/customer1logo.png" alt="Customer 1" />
</div>
<div class="customer-item" <img src="./images/customer2logo.png" alt="Customer 2" />
</div>
<div class="customer-item" <img src="./images/customer3logo.png" alt="Customer 3" />
</div>
</div>
```

I however don't know how to stop element from rotating again when the mouse leaves it.
Any Ideas with this css.

Comment: When you say "stopping the element", do you mean that it snaps back to the original or that it keeps its partially transformed position?

Comment: Actually this is not an issue, you have applied an animation on hover, that will be removed when you remove the mouse

Comment: checkout `animation-fill-mode` from css-animation

Comment: It does need to return to it's original positioning.

Comment: @FluffyKitten That it keeps the transformed position, cause these elements are more than one and I want when the mouse moves to the next element, the previous one should not rotate again

Comment: When you said "That it keeps the transformed position" I assumed you meant that it kept the position in was transformed into, rather than snapping back to the original position? I'm not sure what answers are worth an upvote now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply transition to `:hover` sudo element not to the main class.
What this does? This will apply transition on hover, and on mouseout this will bring back the element to the original state without any animation. Since on rotating the element by 360 degree makes the object in the actual state, the mouseout will not be visible visually.

```css
.customer-item{
  width: 150px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border: 3px solid rgb(240, 240, 240);
  -webkit-transition: none;
  transition: none;
}
.customer-item:hover{
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
  transform: rotateY(360deg);
  transition: transform 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="customer-item">
  customer-item
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use keyframes selectors to animate.

```css
    .customer-item{
      width: 150px;
      height: 80px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      margin: 10px;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      border: 3px solid rgb(240, 240, 240);
    }
    .customer-item:hover{
      animation: rotate 1s infinite;
    }

    @keyframes rotate {
      0% {
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
      }
    }
```

```html
<div class="row col-md-10 mx-auto justify-content-center">
  <div class="customer-item" <img src="./images/customer1logo.png" alt="Customer 1" /></div>
  <div class="customer-item" <img src="./images/customer2logo.png" alt="Customer 2" /></div>
  <div class="customer-item" <img src="./images/customer3logo.png" alt="Customer 3" /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try animate this using `css-animation`:

```
@keyframes example {
from {transform: rotateY(360deg)}
  to {transform: rotateY(360deg}}
}

    .customer-item {
    animation: example linear forwards
    }
```